Webpack: Module "./..." does not exist in container after deploying to AWS
I have a React micro frontend application using Webpack's Module Federation and I am not able to figure out this error after I deploy the MFEs up to a higher environment in AWS. The apps run fine if I run them locally. This is the error I see in the browser console whenever I hit any of the 3 MFEs: Module "./DashboardService" does not exist in container
There are 3 apps in my MFE React architecture: Main, Dashboard, and AccountDetails. I cannot find any solutions online as to why the MFE would not work after getting deployed, but works fine locally. I am also able to access each of the 3 app's remoteEntry.js files in the browser without issue.
Here is my webpack.config for my main app:
module.exports = (_, argv) => ({
  entry: './src/index',
  mode: argv.mode,
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    port: 8080,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: 'only',
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization',
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.mjs', '.jsx', '.css'],
    alias: {
      events: 'events',
    },
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: argv.mode === 'development' ? 'http://localhost:8080/' : 'https://dyokuoph43qil.cloudfront.net/',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[contenthash].js',
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        type: 'javascript/auto',
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'main',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      remotes: {
        main: `main@${argv.mode === 'development' ? 'http://localhost:8080/' : 'https://dyokuoph43qil.cloudfront.net/'}remoteEntry.js`,
        dashboard: `dashboard@${argv.mode === 'development' ? 'http://localhost:8081/' : 'https://d39vnhu5rarlq1.cloudfront.net/'}remoteEntry.js`,
        accountdetails: `accountdetails@${argv.mode === 'development' ? 'http://localhost:8082/' : 'https://d2ormgnid5awt.cloudfront.net/'}remoteEntry.js`,
      },
      exposes: {
        './Shell': './src/Shell',
      },
      shared: {
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps.react,
        },
        'react-dom': {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps['react-dom'],
        },
        'react-router-dom': {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps['react-router-dom'],
        },
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
      publicPath: '/',
    }),
    new ESLintPlugin(),
  ],
});

for the Dashboard:
module.exports = (_, argv) => ({
  entry: './src/index',
  mode: argv.mode,
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    port: 8081,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: 'only',
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: argv.mode === 'development' ? 'http://localhost:8081/' : 'https://d39vnhu5rarlq1.cloudfront.net/',
    chunkFilename: '[id].[contenthash].js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.mjs', '.jsx', '.css'],
    alias: {
      events: 'events',
    },
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.m?js/,
        type: 'javascript/auto',
        resolve: {
          fullySpecified: false,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-inline-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'dashboard',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      remotes: {
        main: `main@${argv.mode === 'development' ? 'http://localhost:8080/' : 'https://dyokuoph43qil.cloudfront.net/'}remoteEntry.js`,
        dashboard: `dashboard@${argv.mode === 'development' ? 'http://localhost:8081/' : 'https://d39vnhu5rarlq1.cloudfront.net/'}remoteEntry.js`,
        accountdetails: `accountdetails@${argv.mode === 'development' ? 'http://localhost:8082/' : 'https://d2ormgnid5awt.cloudfront.net/'}remoteEntry.js`,
      },
      exposes: { './DashboardService': './src/components/DashboardService.js' },
      shared: {
        react: {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps.react,
        },
        'react-dom': {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps['react-dom'],
        },
        'react-router-dom': {
          singleton: true,
          requiredVersion: deps['react-router-dom'],
        },
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
      publicPath: '/',
    }),
    new ESLintPlugin(),
  ],
});

and AccountDetails is basically the same as Dashboard. I'm using React's lazy import to import the dashboard/DashboardService into my main app.
Why might I get this result after deploying to AWS? could it be an AWS configuration issue? I don't have access to see what the config setup is for AWS (it's a work account).
Here's what my Network tab says:

As you can see, it's returning 200s for the remoteEntry.js files of the child apps.
I tried adding the .js file extensions to the exposes section as suggested in a different SO, but nothing changed.

What kind of container are you referring to? Is this Docker?
